# Jquery .find() .animate not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

what is wrong with the following jquery code?

I think it's simple but I can't find out what is wrong. 
Is it possible to use `.animate()` right after `.find()` ?

```
if (!$('#slide-img1').is(':visible')) {
    $('#slide-img1').find('.box-ft1').animate({ "top": "2%" }, "slow" );
}
```

Comment: and `.animate({...})` works on positioned element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to animate an element which is hidden as `!$('#slide-img1').is(':visible')` is true.

First make it visible and then try animation

```
if (!$('#slide-img1').is(':visible')) {
    $('#slide-img1').show();
    $('#slide-img1').find('.box-ft1').animate({ "top": "2%" }, "slow" );
}
```